# Crawling text of a specific heading for any web page URL document in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I have searched and get a little bit introduced to some of the web crawling libraries in python like scrapy, beautifulsoup etc. Using these libraries I want to crawl all of the text under a specific heading in a document. If any of you can help me his/her help would be highly appreciated. I have seen some tutorial that how one can get links under a specific class name (by view source page option) using beautiful soap but how can I get a simple text not links under the specific class of heading. Sorry for my bad English

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get('https://patents.google.com/patent/US6886010B2/en')
print(r.content)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)
for link in soup.find_all("div", class_="claims"):
    print(link)
```

Here i have extracted claims text but it also shows other div written in these claims that is div in div i just want to extract the text of the claims only.

Comment: please share what you've tried.

Comment: update your question, this is unreadable.

Comment: I have updated my question @eLRuLL

Answer (score 0):

By links, I assume you mean the entire contents of the `div` elements. If you'd like to just print the text contained within them, use the `.text` attribute or `.get_text()` method. The entire text of the claims is wrapped inside a unique `section` element. So you might want to try this:

```
print(soup.find('section', attrs={'id': 'claims'}).text)
```

The `get_text` method gives you a bit more flexibility such as joining bits of text together with a separator and stripping the text of extra newlines.

Also, take a look at the [BeautifulSoup Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and spend some time reading it.